# How to fetch query in graphql?

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I am learning graphql. I stuck in fetching api info.

My schema is:

```
const particularUser = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "particularUser",
    description: "particular user field for person",
    fields: () => ({
        "id": {type: GraphQLInt},
        "first_name":  {type: GraphQLString},
        "last_name": {type: GraphQLString},
        "avatar": {type: GraphQLString}
    })
});
```

My main query schema is this:

```
specificUser:{
            type:particularUser,
            description:"fetching particular user for specific id",
            args:{
                id:{
                    type:new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                }
            },
            resolve:(_,{id}) => {
                console.log({id})
                const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`;
                console.log(url)
                return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        return error;
                    })
            }

        }
```

when i run on graphql server it returns null values where am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You have to return **response.data.data** !

```
const specificUser = {
    type: ParticularUser,
    args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) } },
    description: 'fetching particular user for specific id',
    resolve: (_, { id }) =>
      axios
        .get(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.data.data)
        .catch(error => error),
};
```

[image]